# VBA code in single line including several ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Do I have to put every cells range in separate line, like this

```
Range("A6:B" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range("G6:H" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

or can I somehow include groups of columns (from certain cell all the way down) that are not next to each other in a single line? This code below doesn't seem to work for me.

```
Range("A6:B,G6:H" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

`Union(Range("A6:B" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row), Range("G6:H" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft`

Comment: I modified it to work

Comment: Was looking for something to shorten the whole code, but I guess your idea fits the criteria to my query. Thanks, man.